# Is there a way to read information from a file and print out on another file with this code?

Tags: java, io

I have the following code and it is not doing what its suppose to be doing: read a file and print content in another file.

This code is basic: it basically gets information from chat2 (the double type values) and prints them out in the format specified %15.2f in the chat.txt file.

Update: the while loop gets skipped, which says that there isn't a double type value that it is recognizing, but there is one.

chat.txt:

```
[blank]
```

chat2.txt:

```
32 54 67.5 29 35 80
115 44.5 100 65
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class SequenceDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        File inputFile = new File("chat2.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("chat.txt");

        double total = 0;

        while(in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            double value = in.nextDouble();
            out.printf("%15.2f\n",value);
            total = total + value;
        }

        out.printf("Total: %8.2f\n",total);

        in.close();
        out.close();



    }
}
```

Comment: If "...it is not doing what its suppose to be doing..." then what is it doing? Can you please provide any error messages or outputs you get? That will greatly help us, help you find the error and fix it.

Comment: There is no error. There is no change to the files.

Comment: Are you sure that it is opening the input file?  Debug and check.

Comment: Since its not giving any errors, I am thinking it is opening the input file. There may be a problem with ("chat2.txt"), like isn't there something like ("C://chat2.txt")? The text files are in the same folder as the source file of the code.

Comment: The input files should be where the class files are.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me as written.   (I created the 'chat2.txt' file in the current directory ... which is where the application is going to look for it.)

However, if you are expecting output to be written to the console, you are mistaken.  The output is written to the 'chat.txt' file.

Comment: Thanks for double checking. Yes, I think the way it is set up is that it would show up on 'chat.txt', but it does not.

Comment: Well ... it does for me.  So it is clear that your problem is in the way that you are running the code and/or the location of the input file.

Comment: Can you help out with this? I can post a screen shot.